# Rewrite/Redirect URL using IIRF

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iirf

IIS 6, using IIRF.  I'm not sure if this would be a rewrite or a redirect.  We've got a new site and need to 301 redirect old page to new and keep the query string value only.  I need the following rewrite rule.  This stuff is kind of hard to work with and I couldn't find any examples that match what I'm trying to do.

I need this to rewrite based on a specific URL:

> subdomain.site.org/dir1/dir2/dir3/page.cfm?pc=1092

When this page is hit, I need it to rewrite to the following:

> subdomain2.site.org/detail.aspx?id=1092

Notice that it doesn't pull the whole query string, just the value of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to redirect with a 301 to a new (permanent) URL, you should use a `RedirectRule`.

Assuming you have a single web site which is configured to respond to `subdomain.site.org` and to `subdomain2.site.org`, you will need a `RewriteCond` in order to only redirect requests from the old subdomain.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^subdomain\.site\.org$
RedirectRule ^/dir1/dir2/dir3/page\.cfm\?pc=(\d+)$ http://subdomain2.site.org/details.aspx?id=$1 [I,R=301]
```

The `RedirectRule` finally only executes if the old URL pattern is matched, and restitutes the query string value of `pc` to the new URL.